# how register Github application for JWT login

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid, github-api

Hi I want to implement the "Web application" oauth2 Flow, and I need o test locally my login service implementing  the social login on Github.

I went on the github page https://github.com/settings/applications/new

in order to create the application which must be registered.

My doubt now is:

**How can I set a callback url and home page of my app if I want to test locally and I don't have a public address exposed on the internet?**

Comment: You have your answer, but I wanted to share this repo which may help you in the future, which has a step-by-step that I created: https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home page is not used in oAuth flow, it's for informational purposes.

The callback URL can use localhost